# PHP is taking too long to render html tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 large tables on MySQL, `users` with 1538 rows, and `ads` with 5414 rows, when i try to load both of them and display their data on a HTML table, the page slows down, and takes around 10 seconds just to render these tables

#### My code:

```
<?php $getAllUsers = "SELECT * FROM users"; ?>
<?php $getAllPosts = "SELECT * FROM posts"; ?>

<!-- USERS TAB -->
<div id="usersTab" class="tab w3-container">
    <h1>Usuários</h1>

    <table id="usersTable" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-hoverable" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Senha</th>
            <th>Data de cadastro</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($connect->query($getAllUsers) as $tableRow) {?>
                <tr onclick="editUserData()">
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["ID"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["user_login"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["user_email"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["user_pass"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["user_registered"] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- ADS TAB -->
<div id="adsTab" class="tab w3-container">
    <h1>Anúncios</h1>

    <table id="adsTable" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-hoverable" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Titulo do anúncio</th>
            <th>Data de publicação</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($connect->query($getAllPosts) as $tableRow) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["ID"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["post_title"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tableRow["post_date"] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to know if is there any way to improve the performance and reduce the table load time

Comment: use server side Data Table, it will help to reduce the loading time.

Comment: refer this https://datatables.net/

Comment: Why would you want to render 7000 rows in 1 html page? Use pagination and filtering to make it usable.

Comment: why the downvote? even with the datatables pagination, it's still very slow

Comment: +1 for @jeroen. pagination will solve the problem. Don't use datatables as it will first load all the data and then it does the pagination on the data. You should use custom pagination by passing an offset and a limit. This will only load a few rows of data each time you click on page links. This will work very fast as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow these techniques to retrieve a large number of data from the database. When you work on enterprise-level applications, It will help you.

**1. Chunking Data**

When you have huge data in your database, You should Chunk the data as a small set. It means to get 100 data per page & use pagination to manage pages. (With Ajax is better).

**2. Indexing**

Indexing a very essential thing in database design. It will optimize the retrieving process.

[More Info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-databases-set-1/)

**3.clustering**

Database clustering is an advanced technique, Commonly using in large productions to control data loss, database server failure & traffic in the database systems. But learn for your knowledge.

[More Info](http://www.ndimensionz.com/kb/what-is-database-clustering-introduction-and-brief-explanation/)

Answer (score 1):

As your table has relatively big amount of data which is taking 10 minutes, I shall suggest you to use ajax call instead of rendering table at server side.

Like make a static page with two tables;

```
<table id="usersTable" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-hoverable" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Senha</th>
        <th>Data de cadastro</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <!-- Render this section via JS ajax success function -->
    </tbody>
</table>


<!-- table 2-->
<table id="adsTable" class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-hoverable" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Titulo do anúncio</th>
        <th>Data de publicação</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Render this section via JS ajax success function -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now in page load use two different ajax call to fetch the data in JSON format.

In PHP side you can compress the data in gzip format to make data even smaller;

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($gzipoutput));
```

So if you do that, you will get facilities like;

**1. Data for two tables will be fetched parallel**

**2. Non blocking UI**

**3. GZIP encoding will decrease the transferred data amount**

Now if it is possible I would like to suggest to use pagination in your table (though I am not aware your requirement). If you use pagination it will really help to make the page much much faster. FYI, if you try to implement pagination by own coding it will be a bit time consuming rather you can use some kind of JS library for grid (e.g. `JqGrid, JQuery data table, Handsontable` etc)

Apart from this there are some advance solution if you really want to stick with PHP only. Like;

1. Clustering the database
2. Indexing the tables to fetch data quickly
3. Use PHP's P-Thread to fetch data in parallel manner.